# Existance of Android ViewAttachedToActivity event?

Tags: android, events, view, fonts, listener

I'm looking in the documentation for some kind of an event that would allow me to detect when either a view is created or when the view is attached to the activity, anywhere in the view hierarchy, whether it's one level deep or multiple levels deep.

A method like this would be ideal, either at the Activity level, Window level, or Window.DecorView level:

```
void ViewAttachedToActivity(View view)
{
    ... //triggered each time an individual view is added to activity
}
```

The important part is that I want to be able to detect this event from the context of the Activity, not from the context of the child view itself.

Below is a rough demo of what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm wondering if a more efficient method exists:

P.S. I know I can accomplish the custom font part by subclassing all the text controls like TextView, EditText, Button, etc, and use them instead of the stock controls, but I'm looking for a simple workaround that might help me to avoid that.

(Please excuse the fact that this code is written in C# using Mono for Android, it should be simple to understand and mentally convert to Java)

```
public class BaseActivity : SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    public Typeface Voltaire { get; set; }
    bool pendingLayout = false;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Voltaire = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/voltaire-regular.ttf");
        Window.DecorView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += new EventHandler(ViewTreeObserver_GlobalLayout);
        Window.DecorView.ViewTreeObserver.PreDraw += new EventHandler<ViewTreeObserver.PreDrawEventArgs>(ViewTreeObserver_PreDraw);
    }

    void ViewTreeObserver_GlobalLayout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pendingLayout = true;
    }

    void ViewTreeObserver_PreDraw(object sender, ViewTreeObserver.PreDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pendingLayout)
        {
            pendingLayout = false;
            SetTypeFace(Window.DecorView, Voltaire);
        }
    }

    public void SetTypeFace(View view, Typeface typeface)
    {
        if (view is TextView)
        {
            ((TextView)view).Typeface = typeface;
        }

        if (view is ViewGroup)
        {
            ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewgroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                SetTypeFace(viewgroup.GetChildAt(i), typeface);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think an event like this exists